# Not all code paths have a return value

Tags: c#

This is very strange because as far as I can tell the method does return a value or null...I have ran it with null before and it worked...ever since I entered those 2 if statements inside the if statement, I am getting the error "not all code paths have a return value"

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {

        if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length > 40)
        {

        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(0, 36);
        string ReportIDNumtwo = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(36, 36);
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting = ReportIDNumtwo;
        return ReportID;

        }

        else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39)
        {
            string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
            MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
            return ReportID;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an `else` after `else if`

Comment: What if the report ID is 40? It wouldn't return...

Comment: You got 7 answers after 3 minutes :-)

Comment: it can never be 40, they are of predetermined string length

Comment: @Nadal the compiler doesn't know that

Comment: @Nadal - The compiler only can determine that not all paths return a value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    ...

    else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39)
    {
        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        return ReportID;
     }

    // it's possible to get here without returning anything
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

So you should do something like this:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    ...

    else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39)
    {
        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        return ReportID;
     }
}

return null;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking it would enter one of those if statement and if none of the nested if statements were met it would go to the else statement outside but I guess that something was a problem in there

Answer (score 4):

Inside the first `if`, when both conditions are `false`. For example if the number of rows is 40.

Comment: i thought it would run the outter else statement if the very first if statement isnt true since if the first if statement is true then one of the  nested if statements have to be true as well

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an `else` in the inner `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `else` statement at the end and keep the `return null;` it should go away. If it reaches an inner `if` statement, it would return something, but if it reaches the end, it would not be able to return anything.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count != 0){
    if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length > 40)
    {
        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(0, 36);
        string ReportIDNumtwo = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(36, 36);
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting = ReportIDNumtwo;
        return ReportID;
    }
    else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39){
        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        return ReportID;
    }
}
// If gets into if statement, but does not match inner conditional statements, it will end up here, if it were an else statement, return null will not get called, and a return will not be done
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no return value for when `dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length == 39` or `dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length == 40`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
string ReportID = null;

if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{

    if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length > 40)
    {

    ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(0, 36);
    string ReportIDNumtwo = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(36, 36);
    MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
    MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting = ReportIDNumtwo;

    }

    else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39)
    {
        ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
     }
}

return ReportID;
```

Reason: Less code, one return point.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `else` after `else if`:

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {

        if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length > 40)
        {

        string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(0, 36);
        string ReportIDNumtwo = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Substring(36, 36);
        MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
        MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting = ReportIDNumtwo;
        return ReportID;

        }

        else if (dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString().Length < 39)
        {
            string ReportID = dt.Rows[0]["ReportID"].ToString();
            MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting = ReportID;
            return ReportID;
        }
        else
        {
            return null /* or something */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is redundant, but it matches the posters coding style.

Comment: The coding style is wrong, which is why he has a problem in the first place.

Comment: 'the coding style is wrong' ... huh? I think it's error prone and verbose, but not wrong.

Comment: @0A0D I remember having professors that graded tests like that. I despised those professors.

Comment: @0A0D I know it's redundant. I put `else` so it would be clear to @Nadal that there is one more case where length equals exactly 40. This code clearly needs refactoring and it goes beyond removing `else`  statements.

Comment: This would not survive a peer review.